# Are ArrayLists and Arrays represented differently in JSON?

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

In my Java application I would like to use an `ArrayList` within one of my classes.

However when converting this to JSON the front end expects an array.

How are `ArrayList`s represented in JSON when converted using Gson? Are they the same structure as an array?

Comment: The JSON representation is the same, `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both objects will be represented the same (sing the notation **[ ]** for both)...

see this:

```
List<Foo> myList = Arrays.asList(new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(3));

Foo[] fooArray = {new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(3)};

Gson g = new Gson();
System.out.println(g.toJson(myList));
System.out.println(g.toJson(fooArray));
```

both jsons are:

> [{"t":1},{"t":2},{"t":3}]
>
> [{"t":1},{"t":2},{"t":3}]

Comment: I don't think it really needed a test case - the [spec](http://json.org) would have been enough :)

Comment: Agree, just sometimes is worth to have everything on the same place....

Comment: Ok so I will not alter the strcuture of the JSON from changing the array to an Arraylist?